# Java Input from console giving unexpected values

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, stdin, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

In the given code,

> Input: 
> 1 
> 7
>
> Output: 
> 1

Output should be 7. What am I missing??

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class compiler 
{
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception 
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int testcases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        //  System.out.println("If this statement is added it works as expected!")

        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

*I also tried using scanner

Comment: This works as intended for me.

Comment: @pedromss I only want to print one value!!!

Comment: It works normally, I get 7.

Comment: whats wrong with the question? why so many down votes?

Comment: It should print 7. Strange behaviors may occur when you deal with scarce resources. Using a try-finally block and closing streams is a safer way to avoid unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. if you are not using an IDE, then maybe you changed your code and didn't compile again. so you are essentially running an old code with different output?

Comment: It worked in Command Prompt (windows). Previously I was using IDE- JCreator.

Comment: It also doesnt work in online coding contests where input is automated through stdin

Answer (score 0):

In fact, after run your code, `testcases` will be 1 and `n` will be 7 (this will be printed on console - your example doesn't match output given).

Maybe this fragment of code will help with printing last given input to output:

```
int n;
while(br.readLine())
{
    n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
}
System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: yeah, that's the problem. the example doesn't match the output

Comment: in that case, you are running another code or copying output from another console ;)

Answer (score -3):

```
 The code must be like this if you want to use command line argument
 Public static void main(String ar[])
 {

  int i=(0;
  for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++)
  System.out.println(" "+ar[i]);

    }
```

Comment: This is not related to the question. It could be a comment.

Comment: This code wont work. It has several syntax errors.

Comment: I know ..public will be in small and i=0;...those writting mistakes